# Upgrading to ionic v2.0.0 issues

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic2

My project was originally built using:

- `ionic: 2.0.0-rc.3`
- `ionic-app-scripts: 0.0.45`

After upgrading to:

- `ionic: 2.0.0` *(which just looks like `2.0.0-rc.6`)*
- `ionic-app-scripts: 1.0.0`

I'm encountering lots of errors:

[image: screengrab of errors]

I've reviewed the `ionic` [changelog](https://github.com/driftyco/ionic/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md) and the `ionic-app-scripts` [one](https://github.com/driftyco/ionic-app-scripts/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md) but nothing stands out.

I'm assuming the errors are to do with `ionic-app-scripts` *(as that's the directory in `node_modules`)* it's looking at but I'm not sure what it could be.

When running `ionic info`:

```
Cordova CLI: 6.5.0
Ionic Framework Version: 2.0.0
Ionic CLI Version: 2.2.1
Ionic App Lib Version: 2.2.0
Ionic App Scripts Version: 1.0.0
ios-deploy version: Not installed
ios-sim version: Not installed
OS: Windows 10
Node Version: v7.4.0
Xcode version: Not installed
```

**EDIT:**

This is my `package.json`:

```
"dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "2.4.5",
    "@angular/compiler": "2.4.5",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "2.4.5",
    "@angular/core": "2.4.5",
    "@angular/forms": "2.4.5",
    "@angular/http": "2.4.5",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "2.4.5",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "2.4.5",
    "@angular/platform-server": "2.4.5",
    "@ionic/storage": "1.1.7",
    "@types/jasmine": "^2.5.40",
    "@types/lodash": "^4.14.50",
    "angular2-google-maps": "0.17.0",
    "angularfire2": "^2.0.0-beta.6",
    "clean-css": "^4.0.2",
    "firebase": "^3.6.4",
    "ionic-angular": "2.0.0",
    "ionic-native": "2.4.1",
    "ionicons": "3.0.0",
    "lodash": "^4.17.4",
    "rxjs": "^5.0.0-beta.12",
    "zone.js": "0.7.6"
},
"devDependencies": {
    "@ionic/app-scripts": "1.0.0",
    "typescript": "2.1.5"
},
```

**EDIT #2:**

If I copy the `packages.json` from a working template to my project *(and do a fresh install of `node_modules`)* I get the same error as before. It is clearly an error with `@ionic/app-scripts` as I have run `npm run build` *(as described [here](https://github.com/driftyco/ionic-app-scripts#npm-scripts))* and that's where the error(s) appear.

Since the error(s) only came when I copied in my `src` folder, it must be something to with my project as it was written with `0.0.45` and not `1.0.0` of `@ionic/app-scripts`. Is there a possible way to debug and find where the error is?

Also (even though the out-the-box template works), when going into `clean-css-factory.d.ts` and `virtual-file-utils.d.ts`, the same errors are there even though it builds and runs just fine?

**Note:** When running `npm run build`, the console logs up until:

```
> ionic-hello-world@ build   E:\Documents\Year_3\Mobile_Application_Development\mammoth-v2
> ionic-app-scripts build

[15:41:38]  ionic-app-scripts 1.0.0
[15:41:38]  build dev started ...
[15:41:38]  clean started ...
[15:41:38]  clean finished in 3 ms
[15:41:38]  copy started ...
[15:41:38]  transpile started ...

            **errors occur from here**
```

**SOLUTION:**

I have found a solution to the original problem. There was an unused import of a module that no longer exists *(due to the new version of `@ionic/app-scripts`)* which was:

> `import { transformSrcPathToTmpPath } from "@ionic/app-scripts/dist";`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was that I had an unused import looking for a module in `@ionic/app-scripts` that no longer existed *(was from `0.0.45` and doesn't exist in `1.0.0`)*.
The module it was looking for was `transformSrcPathToTmpPath` in `@ionic/app-scripts/dist`

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried Deleting node Modules ?

```
rm -rf node_modules
```

Do you have the latest cli ?

```
npm uninstall -g ionic
npm install -g ionic
```

Change your package.json to the following

```
"dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "2.2.1",
    "@angular/compiler": "2.2.1",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "2.2.1",
    "@angular/core": "2.2.1",
    "@angular/forms": "2.2.1",
    "@angular/http": "2.2.1",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "2.2.1",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "2.2.1",
    "@angular/platform-server": "2.2.1",
    "@ionic/storage": "1.1.7",
    "ionic-angular": "2.0.0-rc.5",
    "ionic-native": "2.2.11",
    "ionicons": "3.0.0",
    "rxjs": "5.0.0-beta.12",
    "zone.js": "0.6.26",
    "sw-toolbox": "3.4.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@ionic/app-scripts": "1.0.0",
    "typescript": "2.0.9"
  }
```

As a last resort you can create a new ionic application then move all your code

```
ionic start newApp --v2 --ts
```

Comment: I have tried all the above methods but I still get the same error. Will edit my question