# TypeError: Cannot read property 'substr' of undefined - source-node.js

Tags: node.js, ionic-framework, ionic2

This error comes as a result of resolving [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41893245/upgrading-to-ionic-v2-0-0-issues)

Here is my `ionic info`:

```
Cordova CLI: 6.5.0
Ionic Framework Version: 2.0.0
Ionic CLI Version: 2.2.1
Ionic App Lib Version: 2.2.0
Ionic App Scripts Version: 1.0.0
ios-deploy version: Not installed
ios-sim version: Not installed
OS: Windows 10
Node Version: v7.4.0
Xcode version: Not installed
```

*(I am also using npm `v4.1.1`)*

When attempting to build `@ionic/app-scripts`, I am getting the following error:

```
E:\Documents\Year_3\Mobile_Application_Development\mammoth-v2\node_modules\webpack-sources\node_modules\source-map\lib\source-node.js:95
      var code = nextLine.substr(0, mapping.generatedColumn -
                         ^

TypeError: Cannot read property 'substr' of undefined
    at Function.<anonymous> (E:\Documents\Year_3\Mobile_Application_Development\mammoth-v2\node_modules\webpack-sources\node_modules\source-map\lib\source-node.js:95:30)
    at Array.forEach (native)
    at BasicSourceMapConsumer.SourceMapConsumer_eachMapping [as eachMapping] (E:\Documents\Year_3\Mobile_Application_Development\mammoth-v2\node_modules\webpack-sources\node_modules\source-map\lib\source-map-consumer.js:155:14)
    at Function.SourceNode_fromStringWithSourceMap [as fromStringWithSourceMap] (E:\Documents\Year_3\Mobile_Application_Development\mammoth-v2\node_modules\webpack-sources\node_modules\source-map\lib\source-node.js:80:24)
    at SourceMapSource.node (E:\Documents\Year_3\Mobile_Application_Development\mammoth-v2\node_modules\webpack-sources\lib\SourceMapSource.js:42:20)
    at ReplaceSource.node (E:\Documents\Year_3\Mobile_Application_Development\mammoth-v2\node_modules\webpack-sources\lib\ReplaceSource.js:69:29)
    at CachedSource.node (E:\Documents\Year_3\Mobile_Application_Development\mammoth-v2\node_modules\webpack-sources\lib\CachedSource.js:12:23)
    at E:\Documents\Year_3\Mobile_Application_Development\mammoth-v2\node_modules\webpack-sources\lib\ConcatSource.js:40:49
    at Array.map (native)
    at ConcatSource.node (E:\Documents\Year_3\Mobile_Application_Development\mammoth-v2\node_modules\webpack-sources\lib\ConcatSource.js:39:60)
```

If needed, when I run `npm run build` *(to build `@ionic/app-scripts`)*, this is the build log:

```
[07:28:45]  ionic-app-scripts 1.0.0 
[07:28:45]  build dev started ...
[07:28:45]  clean started ...
[07:28:45]  clean finished in 4 ms
[07:28:45]  copy started ...
[07:28:45]  transpile started ...
[07:28:49]  transpile finished in 4.44 s
[07:28:49]  webpack started ...
[07:28:49]  copy finished in 4.57 s

            **errors arise here**
```

**EDIT:**

I added the configuration:

```
"config": {
    "ionic_generate_source_map": false
},
```

...to `packages.json` which seemed to fix the error but am now faced with another one:

> `Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'main.js.map'`

Which is thrown when I attempt to do `ionic serve` *(the build of `@ionic/app-scripts` works just fine now)*

**EDIT #2:**

Does `ionic` rely on a source map to run? As the error is arising because non are built

Comment: noticed in the other question you dont have `sw-toolbox` in package.json.. seems like the 1.0.0 version of app scripts depends on that.. not sure if it is the exact cause

Comment: This is not the exact issue. Its a bug with webpack source maps that I encountered too when extending components. Maybe you are using typescript 2.1.5 instead of 2.0.9? I literally fixed it by going to this file in node_modules and adding a default value so it wont be undefined.

Comment: You can also avoid this bug if you cancel the source maps in package.json. I am sorry I dont have a definitive answer

Comment: @misha130 are you able to show me either one of your 2 suggested fixes you mentioned there? I am using 2.0.9 so that's not the issue

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This error comes from having two 2 classes/components in one ts file.

A brutal way to fix this.

Is going to node_modules\webpack-sources\node_modules\source-map\lib\source-map\source-node.js

And exchanging all 2 times this appears:

```
var nextLine = remainingLines[0];
```

To this

```
var nextLine = remainingLines[0] || '';
```

Problem with this solution is that you can't put it into version control since this is node modules

Comment: Hmmm this does work. However, as you pointed out, it's not the best solution as I cannot push it to vcs. Is it reasonable to raise this issue with ionic? I'll accept this answer as it has solved the issue

Comment: I think so. It might be an issue with angular or webpack more likely than ionic itself.

Comment: This doesn't work if your default browser is mozilla...First set your default browser as chrome and then this works.. If it could help anyone.. Thanks for the answer

Answer (score 2):

I added the configuration:

```
"config": {
    "ionic_generate_source_map": false
},
```

...to packages.json which seemed to fix the error.

In the *Edit* above, I have now described another error I am encountering

Answer (score 2):

The way I resolve this issue, was adding to **package.json** this config option:

```
"config": {
    "ionic_source_map_type": "eval"
}
```