# Webpack build fails after ng eject

Tags: angular, webpack

I am trying to modify my webpack to produce gzip files, however it fails to build without any custom config.

My approach:

1. Run ng eject
2. Delete node_modules
3. Run npm install
4. Run npm run build

Expected result:
Webpack builds my modules for production

Error:

```
92% chunk asset optimization  
C:\project_pathnode_modules\source-map\lib\source-node.js:95
          var code = nextLine.substr(0, mapping.generatedColumn -
                             ^

TypeError: Cannot read property 'substr' of undefined
    at Function.<anonymous> (C:\project_pathnode_modules\source-map\lib\source-node.js:95:30)
    at Array.forEach (native)
    at BasicSourceMapConsumer.SourceMapConsumer_eachMapping [as eachMapping] (C:\project_pathnode_modules\source-map\lib\source-map-consumer.js:155:14)
    at Function.SourceNode_fromStringWithSourceMap [as fromStringWithSourceMap](C:\project_pathnode_modules\source-map\lib\source-node.js:80:24)
    at SourceMapSource.node (C:\project_pathnode_modules\webpack-sources\lib\SourceMapSource.js:42:20)
    at ReplaceSource.node (C:\project_pathnode_modules\webpack-sources\lib\ReplaceSource.js:69:29)
    at CachedSource.node (C:\project_pathnode_modules\webpack-sources\lib\CachedSource.js:12:23)
    at C:\project_pathnode_modules\webpack-sources\lib\ConcatSource.js:40:49
    at Array.map (native)
    at ConcatSource.node (C:\project_pathnode_modules\webpack-sources\lib\ConcatSource.js:39:60)
    at C:\project_pathnode_modules\webpack-sources\lib\ConcatSource.js:40:49
    at Array.map (native)
    at ConcatSource.node (C:\project_pathnode_modules\webpack-sources\lib\ConcatSource.js:39:60)
    at C:\project_pathnode_modules\webpack-sources\lib\ConcatSource.js:40:49
    at Array.map (native)
    at ConcatSource.node (C:\project_pathnode_modules\webpack-sources\lib\ConcatSource.js:39:60)
    at C:\project_pathnode_modules\webpack-sources\lib\ConcatSource.js:40:49
    at Array.map (native)
    at ConcatSource.node (C:\project_pathnode_modules\webpack-sources\lib\ConcatSource.js:39:60)
    at ConcatSource.proto.sourceAndMap (C:\project_pathnode_modules\webpack-sources\lib\SourceAndMapMixin.js:28:18)
    at CachedSource.sourceAndMap (C:\project_pathnode_modules\webpack-sources\lib\CachedSource.js:51:28)
    at Compilation.<anonymous> (C:\project_pathnode_modules\webpack\lib\SourceMapDevToolPlugin.js:57:32)
    at Array.map (native)
    at Compilation.<anonymous> (C:\project_pathnode_modules\webpack\lib\SourceMapDevToolPlugin.js:43:84)
    at Array.forEach (native)
    at Compilation.<anonymous> (C:\project_pathnode_modules\webpack\lib\SourceMapDevToolPlugin.js:42:11)
    at Compilation.applyPlugins1 (C:\project_pathnode_modules\tapable\lib\Tapable.js:75:14)
    at self.applyPluginsAsync.err (C:\project_pathnode_modules\webpack\lib\Compilation.js:630:11)
    at next (C:\project_pathnode_modules\tapable\lib\Tapable.js:138:11)
    at Compilation.<anonymous> (C:\project_pathnode_modules\webpack\lib\ProgressPlugin.js:118:5)
```

package.json (put in a pastebin because too long for SO:
  [package.json](https://pastebin.com/0LAZQami)

webpack.config.js (unmodified from eject):

```
const path = require('path');
const ProgressPlugin = require('webpack/lib/ProgressPlugin');
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
const ExtractTextPlugin = require('extract-text-webpack-plugin');
const autoprefixer = require('autoprefixer');
const postcssUrl = require('postcss-url');

const { NoEmitOnErrorsPlugin, LoaderOptionsPlugin } = require('webpack');
const { GlobCopyWebpackPlugin, BaseHrefWebpackPlugin } = require('@angular/cli/plugins/webpack');
const { CommonsChunkPlugin } = require('webpack').optimize;
const { AotPlugin } = require('@ngtools/webpack');

const nodeModules = path.join(process.cwd(), 'node_modules');
const entryPoints = ["inline","polyfills","sw-register","scripts","styles","vendor","main"];
const baseHref = undefined;
const deployUrl = undefined;




module.exports = {
  "devtool": "source-map",
  "resolve": {
    "extensions": [
      ".ts",
      ".js"
    ],
    "modules": [
      "./node_modules"
    ]
  },
  "resolveLoader": {
    "modules": [
      "./node_modules"
    ]
  },
  "entry": {
    "main": [
      "./src\\main.ts"
    ],
    "polyfills": [
      "./src\\polyfills.ts"
    ],
    "scripts": [
      "script-loader!./node_modules\\clappr\\dist\\clappr.min.js",
      "script-loader!./node_modules\\jquery\\dist\\jquery.min.js",
      "script-loader!./node_modules\\chart.js\\dist\\Chart.min.js",
      "script-loader!./node_modules\\peity\\jquery.peity.min.js",
      "script-loader!./node_modules\\jqvmap\\dist\\jquery.vmap.min.js",
      "script-loader!./node_modules\\hammerjs\\hammer.min.js",
      "script-loader!./node_modules\\moment\\min\\moment.min.js",
      "script-loader!./node_modules\\fullcalendar\\dist\\fullcalendar.min.js",
      "script-loader!./node_modules\\jquery-fullscreen-plugin\\jquery.fullscreen-min.js"
    ],
    "styles": [
      "./node_modules\\quill\\dist\\quill.core.css",
      "./node_modules\\quill\\dist\\quill.bubble.css",
      "./node_modules\\quill\\dist\\quill.snow.css",
      "./node_modules\\font-awesome\\css\\font-awesome.css",
      "./node_modules\\material-design-icon-fonts\\iconfont\\material-icons.css",
      "./node_modules\\weathericons\\css\\weather-icons.css",
      "./node_modules\\weathericons\\css\\weather-icons-wind.css",
      "./node_modules\\@swimlane\\ngx-datatable\\release\\assets\\icons.css",
      "./node_modules\\@swimlane\\ngx-datatable\\release\\datatable.css",
      "./node_modules\\@swimlane\\ngx-datatable\\release\\material.css",
      "./node_modules\\fullcalendar\\dist\\fullcalendar.css",
      "./node_modules\\github-markdown-css\\github-markdown.css",
      "./src\\styles.scss"
    ]
  },
  "output": {
    "path": path.join(process.cwd(), "dist"),
    "filename": "[name].bundle.js",
    "chunkFilename": "[id].chunk.js"
  },
  "module": {
    "rules": [
      {
        "enforce": "pre",
        "test": /\.js$/,
        "loader": "source-map-loader",
        "exclude": [
          /\/node_modules\//
        ]
      },
      {
        "test": /\.json$/,
        "loader": "json-loader"
      },
      {
        "test": /\.html$/,
        "loader": "raw-loader"
      },
      {
        "test": /\.(eot|svg)$/,
        "loader": "file-loader?name=[name].[hash:20].[ext]"
      },
      {
        "test": /\.(jpg|png|gif|otf|ttf|woff|woff2|cur|ani)$/,
        "loader": "url-loader?name=[name].[hash:20].[ext]&limit=10000"
      },
      {
        "exclude": [
          path.join(process.cwd(), "node_modules\\quill\\dist\\quill.core.css"),
          path.join(process.cwd(), "node_modules\\quill\\dist\\quill.bubble.css"),
          path.join(process.cwd(), "node_modules\\quill\\dist\\quill.snow.css"),
          path.join(process.cwd(), "node_modules\\font-awesome\\css\\font-awesome.css"),
          path.join(process.cwd(), "node_modules\\material-design-icon-fonts\\iconfont\\material-icons.css"),
          path.join(process.cwd(), "node_modules\\weathericons\\css\\weather-icons.css"),
          path.join(process.cwd(), "node_modules\\weathericons\\css\\weather-icons-wind.css"),
          path.join(process.cwd(), "node_modules\\@swimlane\\ngx-datatable\\release\\assets\\icons.css"),
          path.join(process.cwd(), "node_modules\\@swimlane\\ngx-datatable\\release\\datatable.css"),
          path.join(process.cwd(), "node_modules\\@swimlane\\ngx-datatable\\release\\material.css"),
          path.join(process.cwd(), "node_modules\\fullcalendar\\dist\\fullcalendar.css"),
          path.join(process.cwd(), "node_modules\\github-markdown-css\\github-markdown.css"),
          path.join(process.cwd(), "src\\styles.scss")
        ],
        "test": /\.css$/,
        "loaders": [
          "exports-loader?module.exports.toString()",
          "css-loader?{\"sourceMap\":false,\"importLoaders\":1}",
          "postcss-loader"
        ]
      },
      {
        "exclude": [
          path.join(process.cwd(), "node_modules\\quill\\dist\\quill.core.css"),
          path.join(process.cwd(), "node_modules\\quill\\dist\\quill.bubble.css"),
          path.join(process.cwd(), "node_modules\\quill\\dist\\quill.snow.css"),
          path.join(process.cwd(), "node_modules\\font-awesome\\css\\font-awesome.css"),
          path.join(process.cwd(), "node_modules\\material-design-icon-fonts\\iconfont\\material-icons.css"),
          path.join(process.cwd(), "node_modules\\weathericons\\css\\weather-icons.css"),
          path.join(process.cwd(), "node_modules\\weathericons\\css\\weather-icons-wind.css"),
          path.join(process.cwd(), "node_modules\\@swimlane\\ngx-datatable\\release\\assets\\icons.css"),
          path.join(process.cwd(), "node_modules\\@swimlane\\ngx-datatable\\release\\datatable.css"),
          path.join(process.cwd(), "node_modules\\@swimlane\\ngx-datatable\\release\\material.css"),
          path.join(process.cwd(), "node_modules\\fullcalendar\\dist\\fullcalendar.css"),
          path.join(process.cwd(), "node_modules\\github-markdown-css\\github-markdown.css"),
          path.join(process.cwd(), "src\\styles.scss")
        ],
        "test": /\.scss$|\.sass$/,
        "loaders": [
          "exports-loader?module.exports.toString()",
          "css-loader?{\"sourceMap\":false,\"importLoaders\":1}",
          "postcss-loader",
          "sass-loader"
        ]
      },
      {
        "exclude": [
          path.join(process.cwd(), "node_modules\\quill\\dist\\quill.core.css"),
          path.join(process.cwd(), "node_modules\\quill\\dist\\quill.bubble.css"),
          path.join(process.cwd(), "node_modules\\quill\\dist\\quill.snow.css"),
          path.join(process.cwd(), "node_modules\\font-awesome\\css\\font-awesome.css"),
          path.join(process.cwd(), "node_modules\\material-design-icon-fonts\\iconfont\\material-icons.css"),
          path.join(process.cwd(), "node_modules\\weathericons\\css\\weather-icons.css"),
          path.join(process.cwd(), "node_modules\\weathericons\\css\\weather-icons-wind.css"),
          path.join(process.cwd(), "node_modules\\@swimlane\\ngx-datatable\\release\\assets\\icons.css"),
          path.join(process.cwd(), "node_modules\\@swimlane\\ngx-datatable\\release\\datatable.css"),
          path.join(process.cwd(), "node_modules\\@swimlane\\ngx-datatable\\release\\material.css"),
          path.join(process.cwd(), "node_modules\\fullcalendar\\dist\\fullcalendar.css"),
          path.join(process.cwd(), "node_modules\\github-markdown-css\\github-markdown.css"),
          path.join(process.cwd(), "src\\styles.scss")
        ],
        "test": /\.less$/,
        "loaders": [
          "exports-loader?module.exports.toString()",
          "css-loader?{\"sourceMap\":false,\"importLoaders\":1}",
          "postcss-loader",
          "less-loader"
        ]
      },
      {
        "exclude": [
          path.join(process.cwd(), "node_modules\\quill\\dist\\quill.core.css"),
          path.join(process.cwd(), "node_modules\\quill\\dist\\quill.bubble.css"),
          path.join(process.cwd(), "node_modules\\quill\\dist\\quill.snow.css"),
          path.join(process.cwd(), "node_modules\\font-awesome\\css\\font-awesome.css"),
          path.join(process.cwd(), "node_modules\\material-design-icon-fonts\\iconfont\\material-icons.css"),
          path.join(process.cwd(), "node_modules\\weathericons\\css\\weather-icons.css"),
          path.join(process.cwd(), "node_modules\\weathericons\\css\\weather-icons-wind.css"),
          path.join(process.cwd(), "node_modules\\@swimlane\\ngx-datatable\\release\\assets\\icons.css"),
          path.join(process.cwd(), "node_modules\\@swimlane\\ngx-datatable\\release\\datatable.css"),
          path.join(process.cwd(), "node_modules\\@swimlane\\ngx-datatable\\release\\material.css"),
          path.join(process.cwd(), "node_modules\\fullcalendar\\dist\\fullcalendar.css"),
          path.join(process.cwd(), "node_modules\\github-markdown-css\\github-markdown.css"),
          path.join(process.cwd(), "src\\styles.scss")
        ],
        "test": /\.styl$/,
        "loaders": [
          "exports-loader?module.exports.toString()",
          "css-loader?{\"sourceMap\":false,\"importLoaders\":1}",
          "postcss-loader",
          "stylus-loader?{\"sourceMap\":false,\"paths\":[]}"
        ]
      },
      {
        "include": [
          path.join(process.cwd(), "node_modules\\quill\\dist\\quill.core.css"),
          path.join(process.cwd(), "node_modules\\quill\\dist\\quill.bubble.css"),
          path.join(process.cwd(), "node_modules\\quill\\dist\\quill.snow.css"),
          path.join(process.cwd(), "node_modules\\font-awesome\\css\\font-awesome.css"),
          path.join(process.cwd(), "node_modules\\material-design-icon-fonts\\iconfont\\material-icons.css"),
          path.join(process.cwd(), "node_modules\\weathericons\\css\\weather-icons.css"),
          path.join(process.cwd(), "node_modules\\weathericons\\css\\weather-icons-wind.css"),
          path.join(process.cwd(), "node_modules\\@swimlane\\ngx-datatable\\release\\assets\\icons.css"),
          path.join(process.cwd(), "node_modules\\@swimlane\\ngx-datatable\\release\\datatable.css"),
          path.join(process.cwd(), "node_modules\\@swimlane\\ngx-datatable\\release\\material.css"),
          path.join(process.cwd(), "node_modules\\fullcalendar\\dist\\fullcalendar.css"),
          path.join(process.cwd(), "node_modules\\github-markdown-css\\github-markdown.css"),
          path.join(process.cwd(), "src\\styles.scss")
        ],
        "test": /\.css$/,
        "loaders": ExtractTextPlugin.extract({
  "use": [
    "css-loader?{\"sourceMap\":false,\"importLoaders\":1}",
    "postcss-loader"
  ],
  "fallback": "style-loader",
  "publicPath": ""
})
      },
      {
        "include": [
          path.join(process.cwd(), "node_modules\\quill\\dist\\quill.core.css"),
          path.join(process.cwd(), "node_modules\\quill\\dist\\quill.bubble.css"),
          path.join(process.cwd(), "node_modules\\quill\\dist\\quill.snow.css"),
          path.join(process.cwd(), "node_modules\\font-awesome\\css\\font-awesome.css"),
          path.join(process.cwd(), "node_modules\\material-design-icon-fonts\\iconfont\\material-icons.css"),
          path.join(process.cwd(), "node_modules\\weathericons\\css\\weather-icons.css"),
          path.join(process.cwd(), "node_modules\\weathericons\\css\\weather-icons-wind.css"),
          path.join(process.cwd(), "node_modules\\@swimlane\\ngx-datatable\\release\\assets\\icons.css"),
          path.join(process.cwd(), "node_modules\\@swimlane\\ngx-datatable\\release\\datatable.css"),
          path.join(process.cwd(), "node_modules\\@swimlane\\ngx-datatable\\release\\material.css"),
          path.join(process.cwd(), "node_modules\\fullcalendar\\dist\\fullcalendar.css"),
          path.join(process.cwd(), "node_modules\\github-markdown-css\\github-markdown.css"),
          path.join(process.cwd(), "src\\styles.scss")
        ],
        "test": /\.scss$|\.sass$/,
        "loaders": ExtractTextPlugin.extract({
  "use": [
    "css-loader?{\"sourceMap\":false,\"importLoaders\":1}",
    "postcss-loader",
    "sass-loader"
  ],
  "fallback": "style-loader",
  "publicPath": ""
})
      },
      {
        "include": [
          path.join(process.cwd(), "node_modules\\quill\\dist\\quill.core.css"),
          path.join(process.cwd(), "node_modules\\quill\\dist\\quill.bubble.css"),
          path.join(process.cwd(), "node_modules\\quill\\dist\\quill.snow.css"),
          path.join(process.cwd(), "node_modules\\font-awesome\\css\\font-awesome.css"),
          path.join(process.cwd(), "node_modules\\material-design-icon-fonts\\iconfont\\material-icons.css"),
          path.join(process.cwd(), "node_modules\\weathericons\\css\\weather-icons.css"),
          path.join(process.cwd(), "node_modules\\weathericons\\css\\weather-icons-wind.css"),
          path.join(process.cwd(), "node_modules\\@swimlane\\ngx-datatable\\release\\assets\\icons.css"),
          path.join(process.cwd(), "node_modules\\@swimlane\\ngx-datatable\\release\\datatable.css"),
          path.join(process.cwd(), "node_modules\\@swimlane\\ngx-datatable\\release\\material.css"),
          path.join(process.cwd(), "node_modules\\fullcalendar\\dist\\fullcalendar.css"),
          path.join(process.cwd(), "node_modules\\github-markdown-css\\github-markdown.css"),
          path.join(process.cwd(), "src\\styles.scss")
        ],
        "test": /\.less$/,
        "loaders": ExtractTextPlugin.extract({
  "use": [
    "css-loader?{\"sourceMap\":false,\"importLoaders\":1}",
    "postcss-loader",
    "less-loader"
  ],
  "fallback": "style-loader",
  "publicPath": ""
})
      },
      {
        "include": [
          path.join(process.cwd(), "node_modules\\quill\\dist\\quill.core.css"),
          path.join(process.cwd(), "node_modules\\quill\\dist\\quill.bubble.css"),
          path.join(process.cwd(), "node_modules\\quill\\dist\\quill.snow.css"),
          path.join(process.cwd(), "node_modules\\font-awesome\\css\\font-awesome.css"),
          path.join(process.cwd(), "node_modules\\material-design-icon-fonts\\iconfont\\material-icons.css"),
          path.join(process.cwd(), "node_modules\\weathericons\\css\\weather-icons.css"),
          path.join(process.cwd(), "node_modules\\weathericons\\css\\weather-icons-wind.css"),
          path.join(process.cwd(), "node_modules\\@swimlane\\ngx-datatable\\release\\assets\\icons.css"),
          path.join(process.cwd(), "node_modules\\@swimlane\\ngx-datatable\\release\\datatable.css"),
          path.join(process.cwd(), "node_modules\\@swimlane\\ngx-datatable\\release\\material.css"),
          path.join(process.cwd(), "node_modules\\fullcalendar\\dist\\fullcalendar.css"),
          path.join(process.cwd(), "node_modules\\github-markdown-css\\github-markdown.css"),
          path.join(process.cwd(), "src\\styles.scss")
        ],
        "test": /\.styl$/,
        "loaders": ExtractTextPlugin.extract({
  "use": [
    "css-loader?{\"sourceMap\":false,\"importLoaders\":1}",
    "postcss-loader",
    "stylus-loader?{\"sourceMap\":false,\"paths\":[]}"
  ],
  "fallback": "style-loader",
  "publicPath": ""
})
      },
      {
        "test": /\.ts$/,
        "loader": "@ngtools/webpack"
      }
    ]
  },
  "plugins": [
    new NoEmitOnErrorsPlugin(),
    new GlobCopyWebpackPlugin({
      "patterns": [
        "assets",
        "favicon.ico"
      ],
      "globOptions": {
        "cwd": "C:\\Users\\Moshe\\Desktop\\Matrix-ng4\\src",
        "dot": true,
        "ignore": "**/.gitkeep"
      }
    }),
    new ProgressPlugin(),
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      "template": "./src\\index.html",
      "filename": "./index.html",
      "hash": false,
      "inject": true,
      "compile": true,
      "favicon": false,
      "minify": false,
      "cache": true,
      "showErrors": true,
      "chunks": "all",
      "excludeChunks": [],
      "title": "Webpack App",
      "xhtml": true,
      "chunksSortMode": function sort(left, right) {
        let leftIndex = entryPoints.indexOf(left.names[0]);
        let rightindex = entryPoints.indexOf(right.names[0]);
        if (leftIndex > rightindex) {
            return 1;
        }
        else if (leftIndex < rightindex) {
            return -1;
        }
        else {
            return 0;
        }
    }
    }),
    new BaseHrefWebpackPlugin({}),
    new CommonsChunkPlugin({
      "name": "inline",
      "minChunks": null
    }),
    new CommonsChunkPlugin({
      "name": "vendor",
      "minChunks": (module) => module.resource && module.resource.startsWith(nodeModules),
      "chunks": [
        "main"
      ]
    }),
    new ExtractTextPlugin({
      "filename": "[name].bundle.css",
      "disable": true
    }),
    new LoaderOptionsPlugin({
      "sourceMap": true,
      "options": {
        "postcss": [
          autoprefixer(),
          postcssUrl({"url": (URL) => {
            // Only convert absolute URLs, which CSS-Loader won't process into require().
            if (!URL.startsWith('/')) {
                return URL;
            }
            // Join together base-href, deploy-url and the original URL.
            // Also dedupe multiple slashes into single ones.
            return `/${baseHref || ''}/${deployUrl || ''}/${URL}`.replace(/\/\/+/g, '/');
        }})
        ],
        "sassLoader": {
          "sourceMap": false,
          "includePaths": []
        },
        "lessLoader": {
          "sourceMap": false
        },
        "context": ""
      }
    }),
    new AotPlugin({
      "mainPath": "main.ts",
      "hostReplacementPaths": {
        "environments\\environment.ts": "environments\\environment.ts"
      },
      "exclude": [],
      "tsConfigPath": "src\\tsconfig.app.json",
      "skipCodeGeneration": true
    })
  ],
  "node": {
    "fs": "empty",
    "global": true,
    "crypto": "empty",
    "tls": "empty",
    "net": "empty",
    "process": true,
    "module": false,
    "clearImmediate": false,
    "setImmediate": false
  }
};
```

I've tried to incorporate a solution proposed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41907409/typeerror-cannot-read-property-substr-of-undefined-source-node-js/41923610#41923610) to no avail.

Comment: [https://github.com/driftyco/ionic-app-scripts/issues/593](https://github.com/driftyco/ionic-app-scripts/issues/593)

Comment: @SyntacticFructose I have seen this resource, but I don't believe I am using 'ionic'. Nonetheless I tried the approach, but disabling source maps causes errors, as the browser doesn't know what's going on.